# magento data installs - correct use of

Tags: magento

In Magento I have been using the data install/update feature to do the following when creating a new site:

1. create/edit cms pages
2. create/edit static blocks
3. set store config values
4. create categories

I am certain the first two are valid uses of this feature as i have seen core Magento code doing exactly the same.

Can anyone confirm if the second two are valid uses of data-install scripts,or whether they should be done elsewhere in a custom script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation/understanding of the install and upgrade scripts are that install/upgrade are for DDL modifications (Add table, add column, etc) and install-data/upgrade-data are for data that is populated in tables (Anything with a $model->save()).

Following that interpretation then both 3. and 4. in your list would apply to the data scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding config values - it can be done in `config.xml` file of your module.
Or, if there is already some value in `core_config_data` table, you should definitely use install/upgrade script to override that value.

Regarding categories - I don't see any problems with setting up categories using Magento data upgrade.